# How to efficiently generate a straight line with random slope and intercept in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, random, montecarlo

Consider a very basic Monte Carlo simulation of a straight line `y = m * x + b`, e.g. To visualize the effect of uncertainty in the parameters `m` and `b`. `m` and `b` are both sampled from a normal distribution. Coming from a MATLAB-background, I would write this as

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(start=0, stop=5, step=0.1)

n_data = len(x)
n_rnd = 1000

m = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=0.3, size=n_rnd) 
b = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=0.3, size=n_rnd)

y = np.zeros((n_data, n_rnd))  # pre-allocate y

for realization in xrange(n_rnd):
    y[:,realization] = m[realization] * x + b[realization]

plt.plot(x, y, "k", alpha=0.05);
```

[image: Monte Carlo simulation of a straight line]

This does produce the desired output, but I kinda feel like there must be a more "Pythonic" way to do this. Am I wrong? If not, could anyone provide me with some code example for how to do this more efficiently?

To give an example what I am looking for: In MATLAB this could easily be written without the loop using `bsxfun()`. Is there something similar in Python, or maybe even a package for things like these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [numpy array broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create your `y` array in one step as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(start=0, stop=5, step=0.1)

n_data = len(x)
n_rnd = 1000

m = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=0.3, size=n_rnd) 
b = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=0.3, size=n_rnd)

y = m * x[:, np.newaxis] + b

for val in y.transpose():
    plt.plot(x, val, alpha=0.05)

# Or without the iteration:
# plt.plot(x, y, alpha=0.05)

plt.show()
```

`x[:, np.newaxis]` forces `x` to become a column vector of shape `(50, 1)` as opposed to `(50,)` which means that the broadcasting works.

You can then iterate over the numpy array directly (rather than iterating over it's index) but you have to transpose the array (using `y.transpose()`) otherwise for each iteration you'll get the x-value for each 1000 random numbers.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. There's a dead link at the bottom of the page you linked; the (really helpful) article can be found here for those that are interested: [EricsBroadcastingDoc](http://wiki.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc). /edit: One follow-up question, though @Ffisegydd : Is plotting in a loop faster than what I did, or why did you decide to change that?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me (or I misunderstood you). I get why you got rid of my loop for generating `y` itself, and that looks very much like what I had in mind when aksing this question. I just wondered why you added a loop for the **plot**, when it works without a loop, as in my original code, simply using `plt.plot(x, y, "k", alpha=0.05)`. Or does this iterate over the index "internally"? Sorry, I'm a bit confused about this.

Comment: Oh yeah I see what you mean, that's a complete brain-fart on my behalf. Either works and I'm not sure which is quicker, I didn't even realise I'd modified your original code.